# Python splitting different values types from 1 column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to clean up data that has values that are mixed in with years that i want to separate out:

```
for i in range (0 ,len(fruitVeg_df['2004'])):    
    currentYear = "2004"
    if str(fruitVeg_df['2004'][i]) != "Apples":
        currentYear = fruitVeg_df['2004'][i]
    fruitVeg_df['2004'][i] = currentYear
```

Current year stays the same value though and I can't figure out why

The values in `fruitVeg_df['2004']` consist of dates and string values. It looks to be that the if statement is not being executed, but an't figure out why.

Comment: You might as well share some data of `fruitVeg_df`...

Comment: The way I read your code, you're trying to overwrite all occurrences of the string 'Apples' with the string '2004' in the series `fruiVeg_df['2004']`. If that's what you're trying to do, try `fruitVeg_df['2004'].replace('Apples', '2004', inplace=True)`

Comment: I did think about this, but the year changes through out the data. I'm trying to have just the years in this column, but in the order of the years first appearance, which i why I have `currentYear`